# How to use Chrome headless with chromedp?

Tags: google-chrome, go, testing, chromedp

I'm using [chromedp](https://github.com/knq/chromedp), which has features to focus on elements, fill in text, etc. Chrome 59 has cross-platform headless support. It allows running Chrome in a headless/server environment. To use via the DevTools remote debugging protocol, start a normal Chrome binary with the --headless command line flag (Linux-only for now):

> $ google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222 https://www.google.fr

How can I tell `chromedp` to send the --headless flag, along with other flags?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Find It. I do

```
c, err := cdp.New(ctxt, cdp.WithRunnerOptions(
   runner.Flag("headless", true),
   runner.Flag("disable-gpu", true)))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's works, BUT you must remove chromedp.Shutdown() and chromedp.Wait() when using headless options from your tear down step.

Answer (score 11):

In the latest version of chromedp, by default the headless mode is true, if you want to change then refer the below snippet

```
opts := append(chromedp.DefaultExecAllocatorOptions[:],
    chromedp.Flag("headless", false),
    chromedp.Flag("disable-gpu", false),
    chromedp.Flag("enable-automation", false),
    chromedp.Flag("disable-extensions", false),
)

allocCtx, cancel := chromedp.NewExecAllocator(context.Background(), opts...)
defer cancel()

// create context
ctx, cancel := chromedp.NewContext(allocCtx, chromedp.WithLogf(log.Printf))
defer cancel()

if err := chromedp.Run(ctx,
    chromedp.Navigate(`https://www.google.com/`),
); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```